# In excel, whenever date is entered in one column another column should automatically display date before 3 business days

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

Whenever date is entered in column B, date before 3 business date should be automatically inserted in column C. I get it with `=IF(B15, WORKDAY(B15, -3), " ")` this formula but unable to get it automatically inserted for future rows without adding formula to blank cells. I need it without adding extra blank cells. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Formatting your data as a table can do the trick

Comment: Perhaps if you put your data into a table. Each time the user enters in a row below the table, the table automatically expands and fills the formula.

Comment: Table solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First format column **C** to some date format and then insert this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim B As Range
Set B = Range("B:B")

If Intersect(B, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
v = Target.Value
If Not IsDate(v) Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(v, -3)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

There will be no formulas entered in column **C**.

**EDIT#1:**

An alternative is to enter in **C15**:

=IF(B15="","",WORKDAY(B15,-3))

and copy down.  The **C** cells will appear empty until the **B** cell is filled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not comfortable working with macro. I was curious to know is there any simple way to apply the formula to future cells

Comment: @Mamta   See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I tried it but I cannot have empty rows with formula applied to column C for  values to be entered in B. Initially file should contain only rows with data.